# Query a JSON object in Powerautomate

Tags: json, power-automate

In Power Automate I have a JSON object like this (this is a small sample, the actual bigger):

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "day": 1,
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2021,
            "balance": 6
        },
        {
            "day": 2,
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2021,
            "balance": 47
        }
   ]
}
```

Additionally, I have a variable with a specific day (myDay), I want to get the value of the balance for the day = myDay, how can I achieve this?

What is the syntax to use instead of a fixed value (variables('myJson')?['items']?[1]?['balance'])?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the data type and the value of myDay? Is it an Integer that stores a sequential number or a date, or something else? And another thing to clarify the question - does the JSON array always have entries for every day in a certain range, or there may be gaps?

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDrogin, myDay is an Integer and the value is a valid day (1 to 31). The JSON has the data for all dates, I put only two items in the question, but the full data has all the days of the month under analysis. Any advice?

Comment: Does your json only ever have a single months worth of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the additional details in the comments, I think this expression should do the trick:

```
variables('myJson')?['items']?[sub(variables('myDay'), 1)]?['balance']
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander, it worked! I was wondering if the variables were Strings instead of integers, how can I build the filter? I mean, if I have  the condition to find the value of the "balance" when myDay was "abcd" and the values of "day" were like "aabb", "ccdd", "rrff", "abcd", etc. ?

Comment: If the myDay value is not a sequential number, then you could use ParseJSON / Filter Array actions. This is assuming that the value of the myDate can be exactly matched with one of the values in the Json array. "Parse JSON" action transforms the Json structure into an array, and "Filter Array" selects elements of the array that match the given criteria (where myDay is equal to "day" in your case).